# Pi4 start X server only on one HDMI output

Tags: pi-4, xorg, framebuffer

I have coded a program to display a countdown using PySimpleGUI. I want to run it on one HDMI output of the Pi4. The other HDMI output should continue to run a regular frame buffer as I’d like to use [PiDeck](https://github.com/superlou/pideck) on it (which uses OMXPlayer).

My X knowledge is quite dated and what ever search term I come up with describes how to use both screens with Xorg. https://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Framebuffer-HOWTO/#AEN1010 Is the closest I could find but is totally outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Allocate two framebuffers from `config.txt`

```
max_framebuffers=2
```

Tell Xorg to use only one screen: create `xorg.conf` with `sudo xorg -configure` and edit it to keep only the first device. If Xorg is not using the second screen anyway, skip this step.

Run `omxplayer` on the second screen with `--display 7` as described [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/omxplayer.md).

Comment: running ˋXorg -configureˋ yields in an error. No devices are found. I tried creating an ˋxorg.confˋ by hand with no success. Do you have any hints on how to get started or what are the relevant sections?